# Creating an equivalent HTML web application to an existing LightSwitch application

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, asp.net-membership, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a LightSwitch customer-order management application. The customers can login and only view their orders. I'm trying to create a similar web app but not sure what route to take - ASP.net...etc. since not all my clients have Silverlight installed. If I did this in ASP.NET with Visual Web Developer, how would I go about the authentication based on the customer record in the db? It wasn't as big of a deal in LightSwitch.

Comment: Your title is missleading, real question appears to be: "how would I go about [implementing] the authentication [in ASP.NET]"

Answer (score 0):

There is an article on Codeproject about sharing the authentication between a .NET app and LightSwitch. Basically it comes down to 2 things in the `web.config`; `MachineKey`, and `Forms Cookie`. These have to be the same in all `web.config` files, and it automatically works.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/DNNThingsForSale.aspx

Also, Team Foundation Server has a web front end, and it exactly represents what is in the application.... *Team Foundation Server uses the exact same way of describing the UI as LightSwitch* ... so you might find something there.